# Change the initial url of the debugger in visual studio 2008 [ASP.NET MVC]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I was wondering if there is an option to change the debugger url when I initialize the debugger. I want it to start off at `http://localhost:xxxx/controller/view` rather than just `http://localhost:xxxx/`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC project: setting the start URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982081/visual-studio-asp-net-mvc-project-setting-the-start-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question it can be done like so:

Go to your project right click `Properties` then go to `Web` then change the `Start Action`'s `Start Url` to `http://{port}/{controller}/{view}` then click the radio button `Use Visual Studio Development Server` and click radio button `Specific Port` to the port in your `Start Url` and leave `Virtual Path` to "/"

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio?  I think you can change the default page to /Controller/View in properties window... I'm not sure if designer will let you (because it doesn't map to a file), but you may then be able to edit the project file directly to inject it...

Sometimes it removes the /controller/view for the default controller.