# In my MVC 3 .NET application, how do I change the URL in the address bar on website startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When I start debugging my MVC web application, the URL in my address bar is the following:

```
http://localhost:#####/
```

And this calls the Home/Index route. Is there a way to have the Home/Index part included **when I start debugging** in the address bar like this:

```
http://localhost:#####/Home/Index
```

I don't quite understand *why* the address does not display the Home/Index part in the first place. Can someone clarify this?

Comment: Isn't that the default route? That's what it's supposed to do.

Comment: When I deploy my website, the images for the buttons do not render unless the Home/Index is directly in the address. So I am looking into possible causes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set it up in Project|Properties:

[image]

Select Specific page and set it to:  `Home/Index`

But do consider how a real visitor will be coming to your site, and what you want to happen.

Comment: Your image is broken, though  I think I found the property.

Comment: Hmm, the Image looks fine here.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't quite understand why the address does not display the Home/Index part in the first place. Can someone clarify this?

The reason is that the in the design of MVC, the authors most likely decided that hiding information that wasn't useful would be best.

For example both of these are run the same action on the same controller with the default routes:

```
http://localhost:xxxx/
http://localhost:xxxx/Home/Index
```

What is the advantage of the second one?  It's longer?

So by default if the route matches or partial matches it's removed from the url.

With the default controllers (with a AboutController), the following urls are also the same:

```
http://localhost:xxxx/About
http://localhost:xxxx/About/Index
```

Again, whats the advantage of the second one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the route in  RegisterRoute method in following way:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: That already happened (wasn't removed) because the empty URL is working.

Comment: This is the opposite of what he is asking.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly have a [default route set up](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) in global.asax.cs.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the **Start URL** (*Absolute*) or [**Specific Page**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1982117/175679) (*Relative*) in the [Web Tab of your project properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983445.aspx).

**Start Action** -> **Start URL** : `http://localhost:#####/Home/Index`

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage to the second one. The second path is being used as the default path for the first.