# Start Visual Studio debug session with a url other than root

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

When you start debugging visual studio goes to http://localhost:3896/ by default is there a way to manipulate the startup so that it goes to http://localhost:3896/PROJ/Home instead.

I would like to do this without having to pop a redirect into the main controller, e.g. Not: `Redirect("~/PROJ/Home");`

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 it's under the "Web" tab of the project properties screen. I can't remember if it's the same in 2013 however.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC project: setting the start URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982081/visual-studio-asp-net-mvc-project-setting-the-start-url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Project properties>Web>Start Actions>Start URL

Populate that field with `http://localhost:3896/PROJ/Home` and select the radio button.