# Visual studio in debug mode opens in file protocol

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

When I run my mvc project in debug mode in Visual studio 2015, the startup page opens as file:`///P://localhost:11587/`

The other developers are not facing this issue for the same project which we pull from TFS every morning. 
[image]

Comment: Somehow you've set this URL as the startup URL for your project. Check the debug settings. I suspect this is a duplicate of [Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC project: setting the start URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982081/visual-studio-asp-net-mvc-project-setting-the-start-url)

Comment: This is a user-level setting so pulling won't affect it. After all, each developer in a team needs to use a different debug setting

Comment: The equivalent project page in VS 2015 [is the Debug page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/debug-page-project-designer?view=vs-2015)